# Best way to hide keyboard in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to know the best way to hide keyboard after entering the text to EditText.

1) setonfocuschangelistener : Does this listener is fired only, when the done button is pressed or when the focus changes from one EditText to other? When I used this method, I couldn't hide the keyboard.

2) setOnTouchListener : When I used this, I could hide the keyboard, but i doubt there might be an issue with this. In this case, I add the touch listener to the root LinearLayout. Following code I had used:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    txtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    layoutView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.li);

    layoutView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Inside the main LinearLayout, I am using other two LinearLayouts. The issue that i faced with the above code is that at some points when I pressed, the keyboard doesn't hides. 
My doubt is that I am adding touch listener only with root layout, not giving touch listener with other inner layouts or other controls(TextView). When I touch over other controls or some points around the TextView(ie, inner layouts), keyboard doesn't hides.

That means do i need to add touchListener to all layouts or controls inside the root layout?
How this situation can be handled in a better way?

Comment: Thank you friends for your reply. We can use the above code itself to hide the keyboard. The mistake that I made is instead of adding the touch listener to root layout, I added the touch listener with one of the inner layout.So I hope this is also a best method to hide the keyboard, when we touch outside of EditText. Once again thanks all for their replies. So if any users have privilege to mark this as correct answer, please do it. Only after verifying the code.

Answer (score 15):

You can use this code

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This one will cause a null pointer exception if the keyboard is not showing . Please add a fix to that

Comment: @AjithMemana actually it won't give any exception i have tried it and also seen the docs. Thanks

Comment: @john-aziz57 please find heer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Answer (score 9):

My answer on this question:

Add this method:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

If you want to hide keyboard when you touch screen, you can do by this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 hideSoftKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
 return false;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

it can be used to suppress the keyboard until the user actually touched the edittext view.

**OR**

```
 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I have tried with this also before. But it didn't work. My doubt is that do I need to add any other code along with your code snippet? It would be better if you provide a small explanation of how it works instead of one line code.

Comment: try this after i will explain you

Answer (score 2):

A simple check for **null** or a **try-catch** avoids the `NullPointerException` if no view is focused.

```
public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to hide keyboard, just `dispatchDoneKey` in your activity. Keyboard will be hidden if it is in visible state.

```
public void dispatchDoneKey() {
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
}
```